# How can I set up multiple combo-boxes with the same data source?

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm trying to create a set-up interface for a program which simulates a board game in C#. I have 1 ComboBox which allows the user to select the number of players, which in turn hides or displays the selected number of comboboxes. Each combobox should initially have all four options (Red, Blue, Green, Yellow), however when a color is selected from one combobox, it should remove that option from the remaining comboboxes (i.e. if player1 selects Red, then players 2-4 should not also be able to select red). Right now I am trying to use multiple Lists to display the information in each combobox, but the code I have written to remove the colors from the remaining comboboxes has yielded a number of unintended consequences. I'm wondering if there is a better way in which to share the data between all of the comboboxes. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

I have attached my code below to give you a better idea of what I'm working with. Thank you for your time!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StartPage.CS
{
    public partial class SetUp : Form
    {
        // Create a static array to hold the players
        public static Player[] players { get; private set; }

        // create lists to hold the colors for each player
        List<String> player1Colors = new List<String>();
        List<String> player2Colors = new List<String>();
        List<String> player3Colors = new List<String>();
        List<String> player4Colors = new List<String>();


        public SetUp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SetUp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // initialize the selected index to 2 players
            cboSelectPlayers.SelectedIndex = 0;

            // add the colors to each list
            player1Colors.Add("Red");
            player1Colors.Add("Blue");
            player1Colors.Add("Green");
            player1Colors.Add("Yellow");

            player2Colors.Add("Red");
            player2Colors.Add("Blue");
            player2Colors.Add("Green");
            player2Colors.Add("Yellow");

            player3Colors.Add("Red");
            player3Colors.Add("Blue");
            player3Colors.Add("Green");
            player3Colors.Add("Yellow");

            player4Colors.Add("Red");
            player4Colors.Add("Blue");
            player4Colors.Add("Green");
            player4Colors.Add("Yellow");

            // add each list to it's respective comboBox
            for (int i = 0; i < player1Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer1Color.Items.Add(player1Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player2Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer2Color.Items.Add(player2Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player3Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer3Color.Items.Add(player3Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player4Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer4Color.Items.Add(player4Colors[i]);
            }
        }

        // method to create the players and add them to the array


        // handles displaying the number of players to select colors
        private void cboSelectPlayers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedIndex == 0) // if players = 2
            {
                lblPlayer3Select.Hide();
                cboPlayer3Color.Hide();
                lblPlayer4Select.Hide();
                cboPlayer4Color.Hide();
            }
            else if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedIndex == 1) // if players = 3
            {
                lblPlayer3Select.Show();
                cboPlayer3Color.Show();
                lblPlayer4Select.Hide();
                cboPlayer4Color.Hide();
            }
            else if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedIndex == 2) // if players  4
            {
                lblPlayer3Select.Show();
                cboPlayer3Color.Show();
                lblPlayer4Select.Show();
                cboPlayer4Color.Show();
            }
        }

        // handles removing player1's selected color from other comboboxes
        private void cboPlayer1Color_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboPlayer1Color.SelectedItem == "Red")
            {
                // remove red from the other comboboxes
                player2Colors.Remove("Red");
                player3Colors.Remove("Red");
                player4Colors.Remove("Red");

                // make sure that the other colors that are supposed to be there are
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player3Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player4Colors.Contains("Blue"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player3Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player4Colors.Add("Blue");
                }
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player3Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player4Colors.Contains("Yellow"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player3Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player4Colors.Add("Yellow");
                }
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Green") && !player3Colors.Contains("Green") && !player4Colors.Contains("Green"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Green");
                    player3Colors.Add("Green");
                    player4Colors.Add("Green");
                }
            }
            else if (cboPlayer1Color.SelectedItem == "Blue")
            {
                // remove blue from the other comboboxes
                player2Colors.Remove("Blue");
                player3Colors.Remove("Blue");
                player4Colors.Remove("Blue");

                // make sure that the other colors that are supposed to be there are
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Red") && !player3Colors.Contains("Red") && !player4Colors.Contains("Red"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Red");
                    player3Colors.Add("Red");
                    player4Colors.Add("Red");
                }
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player3Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player4Colors.Contains("Yellow"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player3Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player4Colors.Add("Yellow");
                }
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Green") && !player3Colors.Contains("Green") && !player4Colors.Contains("Green"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Green");
                    player3Colors.Add("Green");
                    player4Colors.Add("Green");
                }
            }
            else if (cboPlayer1Color.SelectedItem == "Yellow")
            {
                // remove yellow from the other comboboxes
                player2Colors.Remove("Yellow");
                player3Colors.Remove("Yellow");
                player4Colors.Remove("Yellow");

                // make sure that the other colors that are supposed to be there are
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Red") && !player3Colors.Contains("Red") && !player4Colors.Contains("Red"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Red");
                    player3Colors.Add("Red");
                    player4Colors.Add("Red");
                }
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player3Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player4Colors.Contains("Blue"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player3Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player4Colors.Add("Blue");
                }
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Green") && !player3Colors.Contains("Green") && !player4Colors.Contains("Green"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Green");
                    player3Colors.Add("Green");
                    player4Colors.Add("Green");
                }
            }
            else if (cboPlayer1Color.SelectedItem == "Green")
            {
                // remove green from the other comboboxes
                player2Colors.Remove("Green");
                player3Colors.Remove("Green");
                player4Colors.Remove("Green");

                // make sure that the other colors that are supposed to be there are
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Red") && !player3Colors.Contains("Red") && !player4Colors.Contains("Red"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Red");
                    player3Colors.Add("Red");
                    player4Colors.Add("Red");
                }
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player3Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player4Colors.Contains("Blue"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player3Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player4Colors.Add("Blue");
                }
                if (!player2Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player3Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player4Colors.Contains("Yellow"))
                {
                    player2Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player3Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player4Colors.Add("Yellow");
                }
            }
            // clear and then update the other comboboxes
            cboPlayer2Color.Items.Clear();
            cboPlayer3Color.Items.Clear();
            cboPlayer4Color.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < player2Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer2Color.Items.Add(player2Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player3Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer3Color.Items.Add(player3Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player4Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer4Color.Items.Add(player4Colors[i]);
            }
        }

        // handles removing player2's selected color from other comboboxes
        private void cboPlayer2Color_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboPlayer2Color.SelectedItem == "Red")
            {
                // remove red from the other comboboxes
                player1Colors.Remove("Red");
                player3Colors.Remove("Red");
                player4Colors.Remove("Red");

                // make sure that the other colors that are supposed to be there are
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player3Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player4Colors.Contains("Blue"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player3Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player4Colors.Add("Blue");
                }
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player3Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player4Colors.Contains("Yellow"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player3Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player4Colors.Add("Yellow");
                }
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Green") && !player3Colors.Contains("Green") && !player4Colors.Contains("Green"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Green");
                    player3Colors.Add("Green");
                    player4Colors.Add("Green");
                }
            }
            else if (cboPlayer2Color.SelectedItem == "Blue")
            {
                // remove blue from the other comboboxes
                player1Colors.Remove("Blue");
                player3Colors.Remove("Blue");
                player4Colors.Remove("Blue");

                // make sure that the other colors that are supposed to be there are
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Red") && !player3Colors.Contains("Red") && !player4Colors.Contains("Red"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Red");
                    player3Colors.Add("Red");
                    player4Colors.Add("Red");
                }
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player3Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player4Colors.Contains("Yellow"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player3Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player4Colors.Add("Yellow");
                }
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Green") && !player3Colors.Contains("Green") && !player4Colors.Contains("Green"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Green");
                    player3Colors.Add("Green");
                    player4Colors.Add("Green");
                }
            }
            else if (cboPlayer2Color.SelectedItem == "Yellow")
            {
                // remove yellow from the other comboboxes
                player1Colors.Remove("Yellow");
                player3Colors.Remove("Yellow");
                player4Colors.Remove("Yellow");

                // make sure that the other colors that are supposed to be there are
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Red") && !player3Colors.Contains("Red") && !player4Colors.Contains("Red"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Red");
                    player3Colors.Add("Red");
                    player4Colors.Add("Red");
                }
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player3Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player4Colors.Contains("Blue"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player3Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player4Colors.Add("Blue");
                }
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Green") && !player3Colors.Contains("Green") && !player4Colors.Contains("Green"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Green");
                    player3Colors.Add("Green");
                    player4Colors.Add("Green");
                }
            }
            else if (cboPlayer2Color.SelectedItem == "Green")
            {
                // remove green from the other comboboxes
                player1Colors.Remove("Green");
                player3Colors.Remove("Green");
                player4Colors.Remove("Green");

                // make sure that the other colors that are supposed to be there are
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Red") && !player3Colors.Contains("Red") && !player4Colors.Contains("Red"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Red");
                    player3Colors.Add("Red");
                    player4Colors.Add("Red");
                }
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player3Colors.Contains("Blue") && !player4Colors.Contains("Blue"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player3Colors.Add("Blue");
                    player4Colors.Add("Blue");
                }
                if (!player1Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player3Colors.Contains("Yellow") && !player4Colors.Contains("Yellow"))
                {
                    player1Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player3Colors.Add("Yellow");
                    player4Colors.Add("Yellow");
                }
            }
            // clear and then update the other comboboxes
            cboPlayer1Color.Items.Clear();
            cboPlayer3Color.Items.Clear();
            cboPlayer4Color.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < player2Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer2Color.Items.Add(player2Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player3Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer3Color.Items.Add(player3Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player4Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer4Color.Items.Add(player4Colors[i]);
            }
        }

        // handles removing player3's selected color from other comboboxes
        private void cboPlayer3Color_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // handles removing player4's selected color from other comboboxes
        private void cboPlayer4Color_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        /* method to update the comboBoxes
        private void updateComboBoxes()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < player1Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer1Color.Items.Add(player1Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player2Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer2Color.Items.Add(player2Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player3Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer3Color.Items.Add(player3Colors[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < player4Colors.Count; ++i)
            {
                cboPlayer4Color.Items.Add(player4Colors[i]);
            }
        }*/

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Control control = new Control(players); 
            GameBoard gameboard = new GameBoard();
            gameboard.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the unintended consequences?  Does this code produce an error?  You didn't really ask much of a question.

Comment: Unintended consequences include: After selecting 'Red' for player1, if player2 has selected a color, player1's choices will either be blank (meaning he/she can't change their mind about their color), or the colors will be repeated so rather than having 3 options, player1 now has 7 options. The code does not produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up doing it (added a "Select" option to make it a little more logical in order to "unselect" a color):

```
List<string> colors = new List<string>() { "Select", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow" };
List<ComboBox> combos = new List<ComboBox>();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  combos.AddRange(new ComboBox[] { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3, comboBox4 });
  foreach (ComboBox cb in combos) {
    cb.Items.AddRange(colors.ToArray());
    cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
    cb.SelectedIndexChanged += cb_SelectedIndexChanged;
  }
}

void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  List<string> selectedColors = new List<string>();
  foreach (ComboBox cb1 in combos) {
    if (cb1.SelectedIndex > 0) {
      selectedColors.Add(cb1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
    foreach (ComboBox cb2 in combos.Where(x => !x.Equals(cb1))) {
      if (cb2.SelectedIndex > 0) {
        if (cb1.Items.Contains(cb2.SelectedItem.ToString())) {
          cb1.Items.Remove(cb2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  foreach (ComboBox cb in combos) {
    foreach (string c in colors) {
      if (!selectedColors.Contains(c) && !cb.Items.Contains(c)) {
        cb.Items.Add(c);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, the logic is to get all of the colors that are selected into a list, then check if that color is showing up in the other lists, and if so, then remove it.  Then you go back through the ComboBox items to see if any color is missing, and if so, add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else happens upon this post, I wanted to post my code after including LarsTech's code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StartPage.CS
{
    public partial class SetUp : Form
    {
        // Create a static array to hold the players
        public static Player[] players { get; private set; }

        // create lists to hold the colors for each player, as well as the comboBoxes
        List<String> colors = new List<String> { "Select Color","Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green" };
        List<ComboBox> combos = new List<ComboBox>();

        // constructor
        public SetUp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // add colors to ComboBoxes and set the initial index
            combos.AddRange(new ComboBox[] { cboPlayer1Color, cboPlayer2Color, cboPlayer3Color, cboPlayer4Color });
            foreach (ComboBox combo in combos)
            {
                combo.Items.AddRange(colors.ToArray());
                combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                combo.SelectedIndexChanged += combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
            }
        }

        // eventhandling for form load
        private void SetUp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // initialize the selected index to 2 players
            cboSelectPlayers.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        // handles displaying the number of players to select colors
        private void cboSelectPlayers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // reset each combobox to index 0
            foreach (ComboBox cbox in combos)
            {
                cbox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

            // Hide or Show comboboxes based on how many players are selected
            if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedIndex == 0) // if players = 2
            {
                lblPlayer3Select.Hide();
                cboPlayer3Color.Hide();
                lblPlayer4Select.Hide();
                cboPlayer4Color.Hide();
            }
            else if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedIndex == 1) // if players = 3
            {
                lblPlayer3Select.Show();
                cboPlayer3Color.Show();
                lblPlayer4Select.Hide();
                cboPlayer4Color.Hide();
            }
            else if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedIndex == 2) // if players  4
            {
                lblPlayer3Select.Show();
                cboPlayer3Color.Show();
                lblPlayer4Select.Show();
                cboPlayer4Color.Show();
            }
        }

        // handles making sure that the same color can't be used by multiple players
        public void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<String> selectedColors = new List<String>();
            foreach (ComboBox cb1 in combos)
            {
                if (cb1.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    selectedColors.Add(cb1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                }

                foreach (ComboBox cb2 in combos.Where(x => !x.Equals(cb1)))
                {
                    if (cb2.SelectedIndex > 0)
                    {
                        if (cb1.Items.Contains(cb2.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                        {
                            cb1.Items.Remove(cb2.SelectedItem.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (ComboBox cb in combos)
            {
                foreach (String c in colors)
                {
                    if (!selectedColors.Contains(c) && !cb.Items.Contains(c))
                    {
                        cb.Items.Add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // handles form validation
        private Boolean formValidation()
        {
            if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString() == "2") // if number of players = 2
            {
                // display error message if one of the players hasn't selected a color and return false
                if (cboPlayer1Color.SelectedIndex < 1 || cboPlayer2Color.SelectedIndex < 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a color for each player!");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    players = new Player[2];
                    createPlayers(2);
                }
            }
            else if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString() == "3") // if number of players = 3
            {
                // display error message if one of the players hasn't selected a color and return false
                if (cboPlayer1Color.SelectedIndex < 1 || cboPlayer2Color.SelectedIndex < 1 || cboPlayer3Color.SelectedIndex < 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a color for each player!");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    players = new Player[3];
                    createPlayers(3);
                }
            }
            else if (cboSelectPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString() == "4") // number of players = 4
            {
                // display error message if one of the players hasn't selected a color and return false
                if (cboPlayer1Color.SelectedIndex < 1 || cboPlayer2Color.SelectedIndex < 1 || cboPlayer3Color.SelectedIndex < 1 || cboPlayer4Color.SelectedIndex < 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a color for each player!");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    players = new Player[4];
                    createPlayers(4);
                }
            }

            // if no errors were found in validation, return true
            return true;
        }

        // create players and add them to the static array
        private void createPlayers(int numPlayers)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
            {
                if (combos[i].SelectedItem.ToString() == "Red")
                {
                    players[i] = new Player(Color.Red);
                }
                else if (combos[i].SelectedItem.ToString() == "Blue")
                {
                    players[i] = new Player(Color.Blue);
                }
                else if (combos[i].SelectedItem.ToString() == "Yellow")
                {
                    players[i] = new Player(Color.Yellow);
                }
                else if (combos[i].SelectedItem.ToString() == "Green")
                {
                    players[i] = new Player(Color.Green);
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (formValidation())
            {
                GameBoard gameboard = new GameBoard();
                gameboard.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```